# When launching WPF app from a batch file, mainWindow_Closing event doesn'y work

Tags: c#, wpf, relative-path

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace Calculator_Assessment
{
    ...

        private void mainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            string copyPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "/Desktop/meme" + rand.Next() + ".mp4";

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                copyPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "/Desktop/meme" + rand.Next() + ".mp4";
                File.Copy("meme.mp4", copyPath, true);
            }

            e.Cancel = true;
            new MainWindow(0).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

There is my code, basically when the user tries to close the application it runs another instance of itself etc etc. This work perfectly when loaded from the .exe itself but when called from a batch file;

```
@echo off
start "Calculator Assessment.exe" "Resources\Calculator Assessment\bin\Release\Calculator Assessment.exe"
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas? All the program does when loaded from this batch (and when i try to exit), is hang for a sec and then seemingly crash.

Comment: Specify "it doesn't work". Does the event never get called? if so are you sure it is not called, how did you check? Does the program throw an error? Also you have posted WAY to much code. You should create a new program that is a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that re-creates the problem in just a few dosen lines and post that code instead of what you have.

Comment: program throws no error visibly seems to just crash - also yes ty ill edit down the code - is there some sort of target line argument i need to add to get it to run just like its running from the exe itself? i thought it would do this normally but apparently not

Comment: Also, as a fyi, instead of using `rand.Next()` to generate a random filename use `Path.GetRandomFileName()` instead, it is more reliable to not generate the same string twice

Comment: Have you checked the windows event viewer for a crash details?

Comment: it throws up a very long and hard to digest event data log but it appears to be due to the fact it can't find the original file to copy because it was a relative path - thank you for telling me about the event viewer i would never have thought to look there - and it works! I can't thank you enough sir, apologies for my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likey comes from the line

```
File.Copy("meme.mp4", copyPath, true);
```

Your program will only check the current working directory for the file `meme.mp4`. You need to either ensure the working directory is set to the folder of your executable in the batch file or use a absolute path for the file you are trying to read.

```
    private void mainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var copyPath = Path.Combine(
               Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), 
               "meme" + rand.Next() + ".mp4");
            var sourceDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, "meme.mp4"), copyPath, true);
        }

        e.Cancel = true;
        new MainWindow(0).Show();
    }
```

I also updated your example to use `Environment.GetFolderPath` instead of reading the `USERPROFILE` env variable.